# Launch Eclipse 3.x RCP Application with Window Maximized?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Is this possible, I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set Shell state to Maximized. This should work.

```
WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.postWindowOpen()
{
    getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getShell().setMaximized(maximized)
}
```

There is also way to set Shell to full screen.

```
Shell.class
public void setFullScreen (boolean fullScreen)
```